# socket.io net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Установлен socket.io через npm.Проблема в том, что клиент не подключается к серверу

Клиент:

```
script(src='/socket.io/socket.io.js')
    body
        script.
            var socket = io.connect('http://ip:3000');
```

Сервер:

```
var io = app.core.io,
    http=app.core.http,
    server=http.createServer(app),
    io = io.listen(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {

    console.log('connection start');}
```

выдаёт ошибку

Comment: Порт 3000 открыт для доступа?

Comment: на нем работает сервер

Comment: Если Ваш сервер сейчас запущен, то это скорее не проблема клиента, а настройки Вашего сервера. Доступа к серверу нет, тем более что Вы и ip указали, проверить не составляет труда.

Comment: _`http:/i`_ - слеш не потерялся?

Comment: нет, в коде есть слеш, прошу прощения за путаницу. Сейчас поправлю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была на сервере, файл конфигураций не был настроен на работу с сокетом. Для этого необходимо открыть указанный порт на прослушивание сокетов, вот примерный код настройки nginx

```
location ~* \.io { proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr; 
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
proxy_set_header Host $http_host; proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true; 
proxy_pass http://localhost:8888; proxy_redirect off; proxy_http_version 
1.1; proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; proxy_set_header Connection 
"upgrade"; }
```

Надеюсь кому-то поможет